# Creating A Log Of Files In A Folder

Tags: windows-7

I am an absolute newbie in this thing.

Can anyone help me to build a table that lists all files in a specified folder so whenever a file is copied to that folder the table should update.

I need the list to retain the names even if the file is moved from that folder or deleted. later the data would be deleted by a scheduler.

Also I need the table to record the time exactly when the file was copied into that folder.

Comment: This is a very broad question - have you tried anything at all? You will get more luck if you try something and post a question when part of it goes wrong or you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

I find [jNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) java library which can help to listen to file system events, such as: File created File modified File renamed File deleted. It works on all general operational system.

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941947/1063509 as tutorial.

Also u can install [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) database and add some code to your application which write your log into database. For better data order.

of course it's all good if you familiar with this tools.

Also i think if try to google 'Folder listener tool'

Comment: thanks a ton   i will try with the mysql tool so that i can output the data in html with sorting and filtering but need some codes to insert the filenames and copy time to the table

Answer (score 0):

How about PowerShell?  It's built-in to Windows 7 and 8

```
$File = "C:\FolderForFile"
Get-ChildItem $File
```

The benefit of PowerShell is you can customise the output.

```
##Sort on LastRightTime
$File = "C:\FolderForFile"
Get-ChildItem $File | Sort LastRightTime | Format-Table Name, LastWriteTime -AutoSize
```